# How can I use regexes in Rust without Cargo?

Tags: regex, rust, rust-cargo

I was writing a few small scripts in Rust. These can be run via a command like

```
$ rustc dosomething.rs && ./dosomething
```

These work great. However, I ran into a case where I needed to use regexes. I began the script with `extern crate regex;` It *appears* that this means I need to run my script via Cargo. The only way I managed to run this tiny script using regexes was to force my script into its own directory, with the following structure:

```
.
├── Cargo.toml
└── src
    └── main.rs
```

I loaded up `Cargo.toml` with

```
[package]
name = "wordcount"
version = "0.0.1"

[dependencies]
regex = "0.1"
```

and dutifully ran `cargo build` and got my running executable.

However, when computing the disk space used by the Cargo artifacts I found them to be made up of 17 files, 21 directories, and 23 megabytes used.

Now this is perfectly fine when running large applications; I've seem small Java applications where Maven downloads so many jars that 23M is microscopic.

I'm simply wondering whether there is not some other way to write scripts using regular expressions in Rust. (Yes, I do want regexes because of the ease of using `\pL`.)

Is there built-in support for regular expressions in Rust or some way to keep my wordcount script in the same directory as my other scripts? Is there some analog of the `-L` flag, perhaps?

Comment: I think you're saying that it's not Cargo that's the problem, but the combined size of the Regex crate and its dependencies. The only alternative I can think of would be to wrap a C/C++ regex engine such as pcre with the ffi (and don't count its size, assuming it's already installed).

Comment: You can cause a single Cargo project to compile multiple binaries, which technically satisfies your criteria for keeping everything in the same directory. You can also eliminate the `src` directory itself by explicitly setting a path to your source in your `Cargo.toml`.

Comment: You could use the regex crate without Cargo, but you'd have to repeat all the work Cargo is doing for you. For example, the regex crate has several dependencies that you would also have to install.

Comment: RIght, there's really no _problem_ here. I understand Rust is more of an enterprise or system language that a scripting language and was just trying things out. I can even live with the size of the executable and the dependencies as that is what you get with any kind of build system producing fast, native executables, with a large ecosystem. i'm certainly not faulting Rust here, but was wondering if I could build an executable with a -L and not be restricted to Cargo's opinionated source directory structure. I think multiple-binary cargo projects is the best option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there built-in support for regular expressions in Rust

No, but the regex crate [will (probably) be](https://github.com/BurntSushi/rfcs/blob/regex-1.0/text/0000-regex-1.0.md) the standard (out of `std`?) regex library for Rust.

> or some way to keep my wordcount script in the same directory as my other scripts?

A Cargo project can have [more than](http://doc.crates.io/manifest.html#the-project-layout) one executable. Just put each main file in `src/bin`.

Comment: Ah, I was not aware of the multiple binary project!

Comment: This is no answer to the question how to build a program using regex without Cargo.